# How can I generate logging prints in BlueZ's meshctl?

Tags: logging, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, embedded-linux, bluez

I'm trying to debug a BLE Mesh provisioning process on a Raspberry Pi 3 and noticed that the BlueZ Mesh's source code has additional calls to `l_debug`, `l_warn` and `l_error` that I can not see anywhere.

Some more digging got me to the understanding that these calls are probably related to the ell library. I've tried adding `-d` to the ExecStart line in the `bluetooth.service` and in `bluetooth-mesh.service`, and still I do not see any prints, neither in the terminal, running `meshctl`, nor in the daemon's journal file.

Is there any way to receive these prints?

Or perhaps they exist somewhere I am not aware of?

Comment: I see all the regular bluetoothd daemon prints, with non of the meshctl prints. I can add them here but they are not what I'm after, simply the "lower level" BLE prints.

Comment: In the [hacking](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/HACKING#n82) in the source tree is suggests the daemon has to be run in the foreground to see the debug output